# Hyper-v on Windows 10

Tags: hyper-v, windows-10

I am currently using windows 10 insider preview build 10074 and I am trying to enable Hyper-V for Windows phone development, but it seems that Hyper-V is not listed on the features to enable, any possible solution?

Thanks

Comment: update to Build 10122 (fast Ring) and look if you now see it.

Comment: also double check if you enabled visualizations in your bios

Comment: As @davidjameshazell mentions is not available on home editions,[link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/dn798751) see compare versions link. Which one do you have?

Answer (score 1):

Hyper-V is only available on Windows 10 Professional, Enterprise, and Education versions.